# Proving limit of additive function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *additive*, meaning, it satisfies
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \text{ ... } \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$

and that $lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=L$ (in particular, the limit at 0 exists).

Prove that $L=f(0)=0$.

I believe that I have to do something along the lines of $f(2x)=f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)$... but how am I formulating a written, formal proof?

Comment: What do you get from $f(2x)=2f(x)$ by letting $x\to 0$?

Comment: You get $0$ both ways.

Comment: Hmmm... what does that give me?

Comment: @copper.hat That proves $f(0)=0$. But you also need to show that $L=0$.

Comment: @sgerbhctim No, what you get should be $L=2L$.

Comment: I totally got it now @EclipseSun. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The point in guaranteeing that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ exists is that by additivity it will mean that $\lim f(x)$ will exist everywhere, that is $f(x)$ is continuous(*).

From the additivity it follows that it's linear on $\mathbb Q$.

These two together leads to that $f$ is linear on $\mathbb R$ so $f(0)=0$.

---

(*) If the definition of limit excludes the limit point you have that $2f(0) = f(x)+f(-x)$ so $L = \lim_{x\to0} {f(x)+f(-x)\over 2}= f(0)$